# Is there any way to automate Atlassian Bamboo plan creation and configuration process

Tags: python, bamboo

My project requires creation of build and deployment plans in Bamboo for different Bitbucket repositories. I read Bamboo API documentation at - https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-bamboo/REST/6.10.4/ however I couldn't find APIs for plans creation there.

I could also find a tool named Bamboo CLI, however it a paid tool and I am looking for a free alternative.

Does anyone know how this issue can be dealt with without using Bamboo UI?

P.S. I am using Python as a development language

Answer (score 0):

Bamboo Specs solved this issue - https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/tutorial-create-a-simple-plan-with-bamboo-specs-894743911.html